# How do I fail a script running in Bitbucket Pipelines?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

When a pipeline runs a node series of commands, how can I trigger a fail within the pipeline?

I have tried the following:

```
const failBuild = function(message) {
  console.error('Deploy failed: ', message)
  throw new Error('Deploy failed')
}
```

I see the "Deploy failed" message, but the pipeline still says "Success".

Comment: How / from where do you invoke the node script?

Comment: Just a deploy script ran by node

Comment: Hm. I asked because Bb Pipelines fail when a command exits with a non-zero exit code, and I would have suspected that something invokes the script and ignores the exit code. Without code, it’s hard to tell if that’s the problem in your case, but I’d suggest inspecting the exit code(s) and especially how the exit code of above script is handled in the code which invokes the script.

Comment: Yeah, true hey. It sits within a promise, so perhaps something funky is happening. I couldn't find any docs around the non-zero exit code, so I thought perhaps I was missing something

Comment: I assume you have a `catch` function for the callback? And does the code in that callback do something to inform the outside world a problem has occurred?

Comment: Ah see, this is the missing part - how do I "inform the outside world". I wrongly assumed throwing an error would be enough.

Comment: It may depend on *where* you throw. If the error is thrown during promise execution and you `.catch(…)` it, it won’t bubble. If you then throw an error in the `catch` function, `$?` should be non-zero and therefore the pipeline should fail.

Comment: Right right! Cool thanks. Is this actually documented anywhere?

Comment: I’d say that’s simply how Promises work ;-) Would you mind accepting an answer as the correct one, if I write one?

Comment: Go for it :) I'm more than happy with that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bb Pipelines fail when a command exits with a non-zero exit code. So, if you want the pipeline to fail, you have to make sure the code is not 0.

In your case (note for people reading this later: see comments), you get 0 as exit status, because the `throw` is executed in a promise, but then catched in the promise’s `catch()` function – which does neither stop execution nor have any influence on the exit code.

Solution: explicitly `throw` an error in the `catch()` function.

Comment: Could you write an example?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who might be struggling with this...

You need to return a non zero as already mentioned, I find the easiest way to do this is by passing a negative integer to PHP's `exit()` function.

https://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

```
if($condition == true)
{
    // Whatever we were doing, it worked YAY!!
    exit();
}
else
{
    // Something went wrong so fail the step in the pipeline
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Bad example! The documentation makes clear that you should use a value 0-254:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php :

`Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer states:

> Solution: explicitly throw an error in the catch() function.

So if I understand that correctly, it suggests you should write the script as:

```js
async function main() { throw "err"; }
main().catch(e => { throw e; });
```

However, this does not work: the exit code is still 0, and the console displays a nasty warning:

```
> node "main.js"
(node:32996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: err
(node:32996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:32996) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
> $?
0
```

The correct way to bubble up the error to the node process is:

```js
process.on('unhandledRejection', up => { throw up });
async function main() { throw "err"; }
main();
```

This way, you get teh following result:

```
> node "main.js"
test2.js:1
process.on('unhandledRejection', up => { throw up });
                                         ^
err
> $?
1
```

Which is a little bit better (except the stacktrace is not very clear).